# Virtual RedHat Can't Connect to the Internet

Tags: virtual-machine, internet-connection, vmware-fusion, redhat-enterprise-linux

I've installed RedHat 9(linux v2.4.20) with Vmware Fusion. The installation was successful although I can't seem to be able to connect to the internet under RedHat even though my Mac is able to connect.

The network adapter of Vmware is connected and it's set to Bridged(Autodetect). Also RedHat is using DHCP.

When I go to `System Settings > Network` in Redhat, I see that `eth0` is inactive. Therefore I select it and press the activate button and the following error message comes up.

> Determining IP information for eth0... failed; no link present. Check
>   cable?

What's wrong with my setup? I remember my TA telling me to select `eth` when installing RedHat so that it would be able to connect to the internet which I did. I asked my TA about the problem and he couldn't figure it out on the spot so anyone else with some more experience?

P.S. I'm using RedHat 9 with such an outdated Linux kernel because this is what is required for my operating systems course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue via the [article from Vmware's Knowledge Base](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=977)!